# Exporting Stock quantity of all products to excel in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I want to see the stock level of all products on my Magento 1.7 website in a spereadsheet format.
Is there any inbuilt feature in the backend that allows me to do so.

If not then which table(s) store the SKU and Quntity in the Mysql DB, so I can write a custom query to get the required fields and write them down in a spreadsheet/XML format.

Also if there is any free/cheap plugin that can help me in managing my inventory kindly point me to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download complete product inventory along with there quantities by navigating to  admin, `"System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow-Profiles"` from this landing page, click on "Edit" for "Export Product Stock" option.

From "Export Product Stocks" page, set "Status = Enabled" as for export filter and then need to save. After saving,run the saved profile by navigating to "Run Profile" menu.

You can find the file in var/export/ folder.